# Correct Logout with Facebook LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am using `LoginButton` in my `SupportFragment` and implementing logout like this `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` in another `SupportFragment`.
And if i try to login for second time it rolls up my app in tray and when again reopen it works fine till next logout.
Is that a problem with Facebook integration or internal app workflow problem?

Answer (score 0):

That was a terrible mistake, maybe someone could even explain why that happend.
I finished my `Activity` (AuthActivity) with fragments and started MainActivity, then finish MainActivity and start AuthActivity with

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);`

And when deleted that flags all works fine.
Still interesting why that happend, maybe becasue of some problems with `intent.MAIN` or `intent.LAUNCHER`?